# Comparing Functions by Convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

I've defined a concept that I'm calling Heavier/Lighter Functions for comparing functions, similar to big-O and little-o notation. I'm curious if this concept exists already. It basically goes like this:

By definition, if $f(n)$ is "lighter" than $h(n)$, denoted $f(n) = L(h(n))$, then one can find a function $g(n)$ such that

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=C<\infty
$$

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{h(n)}{g(n)}=\infty
$$

Another way of saying the same thing is to say that $h(n)$ is "heavier" than $f(n)$, denoted $h(n)=H(f(n))$.

Any references or thoughts on similar concepts would be appreciated. I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are looking for some kind of comparison it's important that the relation to satisfy at least some basic properties. One would expect the relation $f(n) = L(h(n))$ to be transitive, but that's not the case:

Consider

$$f(n) = 
\begin{cases}
1/n & \text{ if } n \text{ is odd} \\
1/n^2 & \text{ if } n \text{ is even}
\end{cases}
$$

and

$$h(n) = 
\begin{cases}
1/n^2 & \text{ if } n \text{ is odd} \\
1/n & \text{ if } n \text{ is even}\\
\end{cases}
$$

Then $f$ is lighter than $h$ taking

$$g_1(n) = 
\begin{cases}
n & \text{ if } n \text{ is odd} \\
1 & \text{ if } n \text{ is even}\\
\end{cases}
$$

and $h$ is lighter than $f$ taking

$$g_2(n) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } n \text{ is odd} \\
n & \text{ if } n \text{ is even}\\
\end{cases}
$$

Then $f(n) = L(h(n))$ and $h(n) = L(f(n))$, but certainly $f(n) \ne L(f(n))$ so "been lighter than" is not transitive.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've changed my definition to say that $g(n)$ must be eventually increasing function. I think that may solve the transitive issue.